# How to install packages on Linux or Solaris on non-default paths?

Tags: linux, installation, solaris, package-management

By "default path", I mean "`/usr/local`", or other paths managed by root ("system paths").

I have to install many application packages (by that, I mean: `svn`, `httpd`, `git`, `perl`, `python`, ...) on a few Linux (RedHat) or Solaris (10, in [local zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_Containers)) servers.

But:

- those servers manage many different applications (sometimes using different *versions* of svn or perl or ...)
- I am not administrator on those servers (no `sudo root` for me)

I tried using, for instance on Solaris, `pkgadd -R` to try an install pre-compiled packages in a custom path (namely within the homedir of a specific user, rather than in the normal default path of `/usr/local/...`), but said pre-compiled packages all comes with references to other resources in `/usr/...`:

A `ldd /path/to/local/installed/packages` will show many dependencies to *system* paths:

```
ldd /home/myuser/usr/local/git
  libz.so => /usr/local/lib/libz.so
  libiconv.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2
  libsocket.so.1 => /usr/local/libsocket.so.1
  ...
```

That will not do, because:

- In Solaris, I have no way to write anything on `/usr` which is only writable from the global zone, not from a local zone.
- In Solaris or Linux, I am not root anyway, so I cannot write anything in system path.
- I don't manage the upgrades on those servers, so if any library changes, it can potentially breaks many of my installed services.

**What would you recommend to do in order to install in an isolated way different "services" on a same (Linux or Solaris) server**, each one potentially requiring their own version of (perl, python, ...)?

I propose a solution below, but if you have other alternatives, I am interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I have found so far:

- compatible with installing (**as non-root**) multiple applications,
- allowing each application to have with their own set of dependencies (with potential *different* versions used from one set of dependencies to another)

is:

**recompile everything**

(and by everything, I mean even `gcc` itself if needed, since the `/usr/swf/bin/gcc` installed by default on our Solaris servers is even older than the pre-requisite `gcc` 3.4.6)

All the versions used in this global recompilation are comming from [**sunfreeware**](http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc10.html), which will details all the necessary dependencies, and will provide a link to the sources for each packages.
That works both on Linux and Solaris.

Each package source is downloaded, compiled, and **installed in `$HOME/usr/local`** (i.e. *not* in a system path).
The key is to have a `.bashrc` (for instance) which will **change the $PATH** in order to not have any `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` in it, but only `$HOME/usr/local/bin`.

---

I found over time **several advantages**:

- The libraries in `/usr` can change, that will have 0 impact on the several services currently running (because they all have been compiled on their own set of dependencies installed in `$HOME/usr/local`)
- The non-root user who runs a compiled application is pretty much *root* in his own environment, and that user can launch/kill/update/recompile any element within `$HOME/usr/local`
- It is easy to make a new directory in the `$HOME` and compile again all dependencies for testing an upgrade of a given application. You can end up with several versions of a same package, and test/switch from one version to another.
- You control the compilation options, and it is very easy to compile an Apache Httpd with *all* modules activated in it if you want (as opposed to a pre-compiled package where you take what you get).

---

The **main disadvantages** are:

- Any full compilation can takes time (up to 1 hour on Linux, 3 to 4 hours on Solaris).
  But you don't always need to recompile everything.
- The compilation options are different for every packages, and can be quite complex to set properly
- The environment variables (`LDFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) can be tricky to setup with the right values
- If you don't have a script able to extract for you the right dependencies and to launch the compilations, that means: *manual* process, which is a drag.
  (I am in the process of making that script, and will publish it on GitHub)

Comment: How often do you recompile? When do you recompile? With every critical security update?

Comment: @sjas typically yes: when openssh for example has a new security issue, I would recompile it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

There's an option to set up a chroot environment for every service and installing those packages under that. It certainly involes some bloat in that you are required to basically replicate many libraries into chroot environment. But it does isolate your services from everyone else's and vice versa and gives you full (root-like) control over the enviroment.

This still requires root access to set up and to access the chroot environment.

Subsequent access can be managed using e.g. SSH:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/229

Comment: +1, very interesting. But at this point, my project "compileEverything" is mature enough is doesn't matter anymore: 1 click, 2 hours and you get *everything* compiled *and configured*, ready to work (git, gitweb, gitlab, gitolite, ...): https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris, you can define RPATH using the $ORIGIN magic word. For example, if you have the following layout, you can define RPATH as '$ORIGIN/../lib' in the RPATH of your binaries, passing the -R flag to the linker.

```
/usr/local/bin/foo
/usr/local/lib/libfoo.so.1
```

However, it won't work if the layout is specified by the user.  For example, the user could set bindir to /usr/local/bin/sparcv9 and libdir to /usr/local/lib/sparcv9.  In this case the setting should be $ORIGIN/../../lib/sparcv9.

Traditionally, all binaries compiled for Solaris use hardcoded RPATH, which makes them non-relocatable.

One other thing to look at might be [crle](http://bwachter.lart.info/solaris/solfaq.html), which allows to configure the dynamic linker.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, which confirms the issue I had with pre-compiled package. Considering that the problem isn't just about libraries (where `crle` *might* helps) , but also resources (directory paths expected by said pre-compiled packages), do you think my "solution" to recompile everything is a valid option?